# How can I automate different spacing between text and code blocks in R Markdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown

Consider the following R Markdown document:

````
---
title: "Stack Overflow Question"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "6/21/2019"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}
    - \doublespacing
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Here is some example text.
I want all the body text to be double-spaced,
but I want all echoed code from code chunks to be single spaced.
In other words, not this:

```{r}
## This code is double-spaced.
## I want it to be single spaced.
## How can I do that?
```
````

[image]

Is there a canned or relatively painless way to have all normal text double-spaced, but have all code echoed from code chunks single spaced? I tried consulting the guide to chunk options [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/), but couldn't quite find what I was looking for.

Comment: I assume you'll want to keep double spaces in literal strings right ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I'm sorry, I'm not quite sure I catch your meaning. Do you mean a character vector within R code to be echoed in the PDF document, a character vector output by R code to be echoed as results in the PDF document, or something else altogether?

Comment: I can't put double spaces in my comments here so I have trouble giving you an example :). If you define in your chunk `x <- "hello<a bunch of spaces spaces>world"`, will you want the definition of `x` to be altered as well, or do you want to edit the layout of your code only. Also additional question, should the indentation of your code be altered as well ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Ah, I see. I'm only looking to edit the layout of the code, not its content. I also don't need to change the indentation, only the spacing. Thanks for helping me clarify the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are outputting to pdf the most painless way might be adding some LaTeX commands to your Rmd document:

````
---
title: "Stack Overflow Question"
author: "duckmayr"
date: "6/21/2019"
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}
    - \doublespacing
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

Here is some example text. I want all the body text to be double-spaced, but I
want all echoed code from code chunks to be single spaced. In other words, not
this:

\singlespacing
```{r}
## This code is double-spaced.
## I want it to be single spaced.
## How can I do that?
```

\doublespacing
Some additional body text. Nor hence hoped her after other known defer his. 
For county now sister engage had season better had waited. Occasional mrs 
interested far expression acceptance. Day either mrs talent pulled men 
rather regret admire but. Life ye sake it shed. Five lady he cold in meet up.
````

[image: pdf-output]
Alternatively, you could define a new chunk option using knitr chunk hooks. For instance, you could include in the setup chunk:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
hook_chunk = knitr::knit_hooks$get('chunk')

knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  regular_output = hook_chunk(x, options)
  # add latex commands if chunk option singlespacing is TRUE
  if (isTRUE(options$singlespacing)) 
    sprintf("\\singlespacing\n %s \n\\doublespacing", regular_output)
  else
    regular_output
})

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, singlespacing = TRUE)
```
````

Some useful references:

- [Hooks - Customizable functions to run before/after a code chunk, tweak the output, and manipulate chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/hooks/)
- [How to Create New Chunk Options in R Markdown](https://ulyngs.github.io/blog/posts/2019-02-01-how-to-create-your-own-chunk-options-in-r-markdown/)

Comment: Thanks for the case-by-case solution (+1). I had tried wrapping in `\begin{singlespace}` ... `\end{singlespace}`, but it did not like that. This works. I had hoped, however, to get some sort of global solution, so that I don't have to manually change the spacing before and after each chunk. If such an answer comes along I'll accept that; otherwise, after an appropriate amount of time, I will accept this one. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome update! Works perfectly, and I can just set it and forget it. Good work, thanks again.