# Adapt linespacing to 1.5-spacing in knitr options

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I want to adapt the following code to 1.5-linespacing instead of doublespacing for the regular output:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
hook_chunk = knitr::knit_hooks$get('chunk')

knitr::knit_hooks$set(chunk = function(x, options) {
  regular_output = hook_chunk(x, options)
  # add latex commands if chunk option singlespacing is TRUE
  if (isTRUE(options$singlespacing)) 
    sprintf("\\singlespacing\n %s \n\\doublespacing", regular_output)
  else
    regular_output
})

knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, singlespacing = TRUE)
```
````

The code was originally postet [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56704022/how-can-i-automate-different-spacing-between-text-and-code-blocks-in-r-markdown)

How can I achieve this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: I tried to run the code with \\onehalfspacing instead of \\doublespacing, but now I get the following error:
! Undefined control sequence.
l.114 \singlespacing
I tried to rerun the code in its original form (with \\doublespacing) but the error still exists. What could be possibly wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to define LaTeX package `setspace` in YAML header and set `\onehalfspacing` directly as LaTeX command.

```
---
output: pdf_document
header-includes:
    - \usepackage{setspace}
---

\onehalfspacing

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I get: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘setspace’ is not available (for R version 4.0.2)

Comment: @Martina Your R is outdated, shouldn't matter, though. Please share  `sessionInfo()` and `.rs.api.versionInfo()`.

Comment: I updated R and ran the code again, now it worked. I just replaced in the code I posted in the beginning the word \doublespacing with \onehalfspacing. So the output text is printed with linestretch: 1.5 and the codechunks with singlespacing. So thanks for your help and suggestions.